# Getting null pointer when using intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I got null pointer exception when try to implement a sample code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot). I have some confusing about the sample code there in "Start the alarm when the device boots" section in point 2 and point 3. Here are my [main class](http://pastebin.com/FRHPhXif) to trigger the alarm and my [broadcast receiver](http://pastebin.com/eSNN3cqD) class to receive the broadcast and trigger an action, and my [manifest file](http://pastebin.com/VvHX9FYT). My logcat null pointer exception error point to the if block statement in broadcast receiver class. My question is :

1. Am I correctly implementing code from the sample to my project? If not, please give me a correct one. Because I don't want the alarm to be canceled when the device reboot. I will appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
```

to:

```
if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
```

so it handles `null` action strings properly. That should clear up the crash that you are experiencing.

Comment: gotta try it soon, but what about these code `ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);` am I right to place this code on my `AddAlarm()` function? Because I got no idea about where to put this code. Thanks

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto: "am I right to place this code on my AddAlarm() function?" -- if the receiver might not be enabled, you would need to enable it to be able to have it respond to `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts.

Comment: I've tried your code, it works but when I try to restart the device then the alarm start, unexpectedly the device freeze and reboot itself, I try to see the logcat but nothing show up.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, you are setting enabled to false. That may prevent your BroadcastReceiver from working.

To at least solve the NullPointerException, try:
`if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()){...}`

Although, it is still possible that your intent is null,

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate that you gave me a clue about a null intent and I've remove the code that give me error.